# Are beings like Darkseid and Trigon beyond the laws of consequence in the DC universe?

Tags: dc, comics

In various different DC properties, particularly those involving Constantine, Fate, and the Spectre, we're told that the universe is a conscious being in its own right, that there was an all-powerful creating force behind everything that has its own will and and unique identity, and that there are overarching rules that govern everything in order to preserve order.

The exact details of these rules, and entities, vary between writers, and have changed over the years, but some element of this has been present in multiple forms since the early days of DC as a publisher. We've seen various characters falling foul of this for actions such as trying to change past events through time travel, committing heinous crimes, or abusing certain types of power — the concept of there being lines that should not be crossed, and there being consequences for crossing these lines, runs deep.

However, the DC universe also contains beings such of incredible power: such as Darkseid and Trigon, who murder entire planets on a whim, and don't seem to be affected by any of these rules.

Are they beyond consequence, or have we simply not seen it in effect?

Has this ever been discussed anywhere in canon, or by the writers during events?